# Cython: ValueError: '...'.Candle has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 16, got 24

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I have 3 cython files:

File 1 - `candle.pxd`:

```
cdef class Candle:
    cdef:
        int ts
```

File 2 - `candle.pyx`:

```
cdef class Candle:
    def __init__(self, int ts):
        self.ts = ts
```

File 3 - `feeder.pyx`:

```
from src.cython.candle cimport Candle

cdef class Feeder:
    cdef instantiate_first_candle(self):
        cdef int a = 1

        # Instantiates Candle
        cdef Candle candle = Candle(a)
```

The exact error it is throwing is:

```
from src.cython.feeder import Feeder
File "src/cython/candle.pxd", line 3, in init feeder
ValueError: src.cython.candle.Candle has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 16, got 24
```

I have not much of a clue of what is going on and how to solve this. I have tried quite a few different things without success.

**Update:**

I was able to import `Candle` on IPython, when I try to instantiate an object I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'candle.Candle' object has no attribute 'ts'`

Comment: I don't get this error when I try it. It might be worth showing your compilation script. You could also look at doing `import src.cython.candle; print(src.cython.candle.__file__)` (in a Python terminal), just to check if the you've somehow ended up with an extra "candle" on the Python path somehow

Comment: @DavidW, thanks David, I was able to fix it doing something that I've read somewhere that would crash my code. I'll just post the solution.

Comment: @DavidW, I ran it in the terminal and got a different error: `.Feeder' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'` it seems that other people are having similar issues: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it doing something that I thought was improper as it would crash my code.

I changed file 2 `candle.pyx` to:

```
cdef class Candle:
    cdef:
        int ts

    def __init__(self, int ts):
        self.ts = ts
```

Comment: That is strange, because the documentation explicitly says, that this should not be done this way: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html

Comment: I don’t think this is the way to go and I don’t know what could go wrong, but wouldn’t be surprised if one day it will bite you. To me it looks like as if your extensions have been in an inconsistent state and rebuilding both would fix the issue. But without seeing your setup-file it is hard to tell.

Comment: @ead Yes, I am worried about that. I am getting very weird behavior so it might have something to do with it. I tried rebuilding it a bunch of times without success.

Comment: I'd guess that Cython isn't finding `candle.pxd` when it's compiling `candle.pyx`. I'm not sure why that should be the case though